# Vue-router, переход на страницу поста

Tags: vue.js, webpack, маршрутизация, vue-router

Использую Vue SPA + Webpack. Переход на страницу поста происходит, однако на нем не рендерится текст поста, по которому перешли. В чем может быть проблема?

В консоли выдает ошибку:

```
Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"
```

**blog.vue**(код внутри темплейта)

```
<p class="post-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
<router-link :to="{ name: 'post', params: { id: index } }">Read next</router-link>
```

**post.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="post__box" v-if="post">
    <img :src="post.image" class="post-box-img"/>
    <h2 class="post-box-caption">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p class="post-box-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let posts = require('../posts')

module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      posts: posts,
      post: null
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    let postId = this.$route.params.id

    this.post = this.post[postId]
  }
}
</script>
```

Роутинг следующий:

```
{
      path: '/post/:id',
      name: 'post',
      component: Post
}
```

Comment: Очевидимо `posts` у вас `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В created хуке опечатались.

```
created: function () {
    let postId = this.$route.params.id

    this.post = this.posts[postId]
  }
}
```